# Import class from module depending on variable

Tags: python, class, oop, import, module

I have multiple classes in module and I want to import them depending on string variable.

```
class firstPRODUCT():
    pass
class secondPRODUCT():
    pass
```

In another module I have string variable which can be("first" or "second" or more),
I want to import class string+"PRODUCT", (if string="first" import firstPRODUCT class, etc). Is there a way to do that in python? Tried with globals but it is syntax error.

```
string = "first"
from .work import(
    globals()[string+PRODUCT],
    my_func,
    my_other_func,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to import the module and use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to access the class you want by name.

```
from . import work

string = "first"
foo = getattr(work, f'{string}PRODUCT')
```

Comment: Problem is I don't want to import all classes from module(flake8 errors...)

Comment: @PythonNewbie the entire `work` module will always be executed even if you only import a single thing from it